# MySQL Database Archive

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, myisam

We have 300 databases in our environment mixed of MyISAM and Innodb(innodb_file_per_table has been enabled) tables.Using MySQL 5.5.19 version. I

we are planning archive inactive database.Is there any way we can check what databasese are inactive?

I have checked at the OS level file modification timestamp,but as we have so many database its taking time.Please let me know is there anyway we can check.

Note: Timestamp column is not present in any of tables

Answer (score 1):

(A non-answer)

There is essentially no way.

`atime` should be turned off, else performance will be quite bad.

Just because you have not used a database in the last week does not mean that you won't use it next week.

Comment: yes james i agree..but there are few database are not using from last 2 yrs ..so i would like to listout such databases.(forgot to mention in my requirement)

Answer (score 0):

You can check binary logs for databases and tables...

Comment: its standalone server..didn't enable binlogs...even if we enable how can it helpful